# Retrieving gridview linkbutton value.

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Good day

I have gridview that contains a link button. How can I retrieve the value(Text) of the link button when I click on it.

This is what I have done.

```
<asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkProdCode" CommandName="ProdCode" runat="server" Width="115%" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"CODE") %>' style="color:Black;font-size:smaller;"></asp:LinkButton>
        </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

protected void gridReport_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "ProdCode")
    {   
        GridViewRow selectedRow = (GridViewRow)((LinkButton)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer;
        string valueLink = selectedRow.Cells[0].Text;
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("This is the value " + valueLink);
    }



}
```

As it is at the moment I dont get the value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already have the LinkButton, just use the `Text` property

```
if (e.CommandName == "ProdCode")
{   
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("This is the value " + 
                                       ((LinkButton)e.CommandSource).Text);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure but seems you store your value in the text of LinkButton. Why don't you use `CommandArgument` property?

```
<asp:TemplateField>
   <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkProdCode" CommandName="ProdCode" runat="server" Width="115%" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"CODE") %>' CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"CODE") %>' style="color:Black;font-size:smaller;"></asp:LinkButton>
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Then you will be able to do this:

```
protected void gridReport_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "ProdCode")
    {   
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("This is the value " + e.CommandArgument);
    }
}
```

Of cource you have to duplicate data but I think it is preferable and more convenient.